# What resistor should I use after changing this LED from using 220v to using 5v arduino?

Tags: voltage, led, capacitor, resistors

I bought these LED things without realizing they require 220v (I assume that's for European mains wiring, right?). Anyway, I took them apart, and inside is a disk type LED, with a resistor, and a capacitor. The resistors were all 1000 ohm resistors, but the capacitors all had slightly different writing on them. `400v 470k`, `CARLI MTF 104K 450V 4E30 A02`, `CARLI MEH 104K 400V 5B27 A02`.

I took the capacitor and resistor off of one of them, and it runs fine on 5v, I tried it with no resistor, 10ohms, 100ohms, 220ohms, and 330ohms. All worked fine, obviously each was a little less bright, but my concern is ruining the LED if I don't use the correct resistor/capacitor with the new voltage.

I'm quite new to this kind of thing. Usually I use regular 5mm LEDs, and I put either a 220ohm or a 330ohm resistor with them (no capacitor).

My question is, what resistor should I use with these LEDs to make them as bright as possible, but still safe from destroying them? Do I need a capacitor?

Thanks  [image: Image 1] [image: Image 2] [image: Image 3 (resistors and capacitors)]

Answer (score 4):

Typical capacitive dropper setup. They use the resistor and capacitor to drop the 220V down to the led needs.

Cut the existing resistor and cap off. Replace the resistor with r = (V source - Typical Forward Voltage) / typical forward current for your color led.

Assume 5V Vs, 20mA If.